# Local EJS functions not reading variable

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am using ejs templates in express and trying to attach some functions to the local ejs variables, but I can't seem to add the function from another variable.

```
var fn = function () {
    return master;
}

var locals = { 
    master:'test'
};

locals['someFn'] = fn;

var stylesheet = ejs.render(data, { 
    locals: locals
});
```

In my ejs template if I do this:

```
<%= someFn() %>
```

I get an error, but if I attach the function explicitly, there is no error and 'test' prints to the screen successfully.

```
var locals = { 
    master:'test'
};
locals['someFn'] = function () {return master;}
```

Can someone let me know what I am missing here?

****EDIT****

The error I am getting, is that master is not defined.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: @jameslafferty I am getting 'master' is not defined

Comment: Does the first method work if you ```return this.master;```?

Comment: @jameslafferty ya I guess that does it! yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To state my answer in the form of an answer, the change to make it work was:

```
var fn = function () {
   return this.master;
}
```